# Xcode 8.2.1 No assistant results

Tags: swift3, xcode8, xcode8.2

When on the automatic setting on the assistant editor, all of the View Controllers in my Xcode workspace have "No assistant results". This is causing an error "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1" in buildtime. Things I have tried:

- Remove reference to .swift companion file and add the file back to the workspace
- Re-classing the items under the custom class section of the identity inspector
- Resetting the assistant editor
- Cleaning the build folder
- Deleting the Derived Data folder
- Quitting and reloading Xcode 8.2.1
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode 8.2.1

I tested another workspace from Github, and the assistant editor was working, so it looks like an issue with my workspace. What should I do to fix the automatic assistant editor?

Answer (score 2):

I tried nearly everything ... nothing helped. The only thing wich I recalled: 
I still worked with Xcode 8.2.1 on mac OS El Capitan 10.11.

As I read, that Apple enabled some Xcode features only on mac OS Sierra 10.12 ... I gave it a try.

I updated my development machine from mac OS 10.11 to mac OS 10.12 ... and now it normally works like a charm.

After copy-and-pasting ViewControllers within InterfaceBuilder, the "no assistant results" bug shows up again ... then it helps to:

1. Delete Derived Data (locate the folder via XCODE > PREFERENCES > LOCATIONS)
2. Clean, then build (via PRODUCT > CLEAN and PRODUCT > BUILD)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem started after renaming the ViewController, first check whether you've changed the *class* name inside the ViewController file as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!!
Go to the Product file, it should be at the last in the left panel,
click on it and select the " .app "
Go to the right panel(inspector),
Go to "Target Membership" and check the app file name if not checked already.
open the assistant once again, it should open now.
If not..
Go to the Xcode preferences then locations.
It will show derived data click on the arrow(->)
open the folder
delete the folder for the project you are working on.
restart xcode and your project..
this will work